# Django Reverse for '...' with arguments '('', '...')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: django

Help is needed. I have tried many solutions, but nothing works. Always one mistake. Please help me solve the problem.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/seasons/season-1/episode-2
NoReverseMatch at
Reverse for 'episode-detail' with arguments '('', 'episode-1')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['seasons/(?P<seasonpost_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<episodepost_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\Z']

Error during template rendering
previous

return render(request, 'content/episode.html', { … Local vars current_episode <episode: episode-2> episodepost <QuerySet [<episode: episode-2>]> episodepost_slug
'episode-2' next_episode
<episode: episode-3> previous_episode
<episode: episode-1> request <WSGIRequest: GET '/seasons/season-1/episode-2'> seasonpost_slug 'season-1'

```
class season(models.Model):
            slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('SLUG'))
            ...

            def __str__(self):
                return self.slug

            def get_absolute_url(self):
                return reverse('seasonpost', kwargs={'seasonpost_slug': self.slug, 'episodepost_slug': self.slug})



        class episode(models.Model):
            slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('SLUG'))
            ...
            
            cat = models.ForeignKey('season', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

            def __str__(self):
                return self.slug
            
            
            def get_absolute_url(self):
                return reverse('episodepost', kwargs={'seasonpost_slug': self.slug, 'episodepost_slug': self.slug})
                

        Views
                
        def ContentHome(request):
            homepages=home.objects.all()
            season_menu=season.objects.all()
            seasonpages=season.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'content/home.html',{
                'season_menu':season_menu, 
                'home':homepages, 
                'season':seasonpages})


        def ContentSeasons(request):
            seasonspages=seasons.objects.all()
            homepages=home.objects.all()
            season_menu=season.objects.all()
            seasonpages=season.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'content/seasons.html',{
                'season_menu':season_menu, 
                'home':homepages, 
                'seasons':seasonspages, 
                'season':seasonpages})


        def ContentSeason(request, seasonpost_slug):
            seasonpages = get_list_or_404(season, slug=seasonpost_slug)
            homepages=home.objects.all()
            seasonspages=seasons.objects.all()
            season_menu=season.objects.all()
            episodepost = episode.objects.filter()
            seasonpages=season.objects.filter(slug=seasonpost_slug)
            return render(request, 'content/season.html',{
                'home':homepages, 
                'seasons':seasonspages, 
                'season':seasonpages, 
                'season_menu':season_menu, 
                'episode': episodepost,})



        def ContentEpisode(request, seasonpost_slug, episodepost_slug):
            episodepost = episode.objects.filter(slug=episodepost_slug, cat__slug=seasonpost_slug)
            current_episode = get_object_or_404(episodepost, slug=episodepost_slug, cat__slug=seasonpost_slug)
            previous_episode = episode.objects.filter(cat__slug=seasonpost_slug, pk__lt=current_episode.pk).first()
            next_episode = episode.objects.filter(cat__slug=seasonpost_slug, pk__gt=current_episode.pk).first()
            
            return render(request, 'content/episode.html', {
                'episode': episodepost,
                'current_episode': current_episode,
                'previous_episode': previous_episode,
                'next_episode': next_episode,
        })


            path('', views.ContentHome, name='homepage'),
            path('seasons', views.ContentSeasons),
            path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>', views.ContentSeason, name='episode-detail'),
            path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>/<slug:episodepost_slug>', views.ContentEpisode, name='episode-detail'),
            
        Template
            
        {% if previous_episode %}
        <span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url 'episode-detail' previous_episode.seasonpost.slug previous_episode.slug, %}" title="previous">previous</a></span>
        {% endif %}
        {% if next_episode %}
        <span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url 'episode-detail' next_episode.seasonpost.slug next_episode.slug, %}" title="next">next</a></span>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two url path with same name.

you have to rename correctly URLs:

```py
path('', views.ContentHome, name='homepage'),
path('seasons', views.ContentSeasons),
path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>', views.ContentSeason, name='season-detail'),
path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>/<slug:episodepost_slug>', views.ContentEpisode, name='episode-detail'),
```

In your template HTML you do not need to use coma for separating arguments:

```html
{% if previous_episode %}
        <span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url 'episode-detail' previous_episode.seasonpost.slug previous_episode.slug %}" title="previous">previous</a></span>
{% endif %}
{% if next_episode %}
        <span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url 'episode-detail' next_episode.seasonpost.slug next_episode.slug %}" title="next">next</a></span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't understand, where are the same names? I have nested urls

Comment: Here: `path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>', views.ContentSeason, name='episode-detail')`
`path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>/<slug:episodepost_slug>', views.ContentEpisode, name='episode-detail'),` 
You have two path with same name

Comment: In my post, i fix your problem, there are not same URL names, because I change name for fixing the problem

Comment: Thank you! Everything is working! It was necessary to specify the field name of the foreign key model in the template (cat). Thank you!

Comment: Moves to the next post, but
does not go to the previous post. When you click back from the third post, it goes to the first

Comment: Maybe there is no previous episode? Check your queryset I think

Comment: If it is ok, you can validate the answer

Comment: Google Chrome - view-source:

<span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="/seasons/season-1/episode-1" title="">Previous</a></span>
<span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="/seasons/season-1/episode-4" title="">Next</a></span>

Comment: There are 4 posts in one category. Being on the third post, when moving back to the second post - goes to the first

Comment: @Yurko you do not ordering your query, so you can be sure your first item is the previous episode. `previous_episode = episode.objects.filter(cat__slug=seasonpost_slug, pk__lt=current_episode.pk).order_by('-current_episode.pk').first()` If it is create in the good order, if not, you have to add an ordering value in the table ?

Comment: Need to move from the previous post to the next in the order of the entry in the table

Comment: @Yurko The query I wrote is only for the previous episode, why do you speak about the next episode, I do not understand.

Comment: `previous_episode = episode.objects.filter(cat__slug=seasonpost_slug, pk__lt=current_episode.pk).order_by('-pk').first()` I fix. But i repeat ! We cannot be sure, episode has been created in the good order. you will add a positional order column in your table probably

Comment: Everything is working! Thank you!!! I'll look for information on how to add a positional order column to a table

Comment: Where can I find such information on how to make transitions from one post to another and other features? Where do programmers look for this documentation? If you hadn't helped me, I would never have done this. Thank you!!!

Comment: You can check the answer as resolved if it is ok. And for documentation, I do not know front development sorry. You can post another question for getting more ways to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

according to the error message it seem like next_episode.seasonpost.slug in the href is empty:

```
        {% if previous_episode %}
        <span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url 'episode-detail' previous_episode.seasonpost.slug previous_episode.slug, %}" title="previous">previous</a></span>
        {% endif %}
        {% if next_episode %}
        <span class="span__bootons-navigatiom"><a href="{% url 'episode-detail' next_episode.seasonpost.slug next_episode.slug, %}" title="next">next</a></span>
        {% endif %}
```

from your post it is not visible if model episode has a foreign key field seasonpost with a field slug.
So eithter:

- field seasonpost is empty or does not exist
- field seasonpost.slug is empty or does not exist

**edit after comment below:**

the error message

```
"....with arguments '('', 'episode-1')' not found ..."
```

tells that you use an url tag

```
{% url 'name' arg1 arg2 %}
```

with 2 arguments and that the first one is '' (empty) and the second one ist 'episode-1'. Django url tag does not allow empty arguments ... so please have a look why the first argument (*previous_episode.seasonpost.slug* or *next_episode.seasonpost.slug*) ist empty. Above in the original answer I gave some hints at the end why they could be empty.

Comment: I do not understand what are you talking about? All that is, I showed outside the fields - a description, title ...

Comment: see updated answer above for more details